# What makes a system linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-systems, image-processing

Lately I have been interested in Image Processing, and I started by following this course:
https://class.coursera.org/digital-001, which is quite awesome in my opinion.

But in weeks 2, Linear Shift-Invariant Systems he states that 
$$ y_{(n1,n2)} = c_{(n1,n2)} x_{(n1,n2)} $$

is Linear and non-spatial invariant. I kinda get the second property (as it will differ pixel by pixel right?). Anyway what I do not get is the first one. Why is this linear?

He refers to 'c' as a gain.. (I am guessing that is a contrast or brightness of a pixel?)

Now the way I see it, is that I try to visualize a straight line and if I can than the system is Linear. It looks like a $$y = ax$$ equation right (where 'a' is constant!)?

But what buffles me is the 'c' value. why does it change per the coordinates? I mean if it has a different value for coordinates, $$n_1=4,n_2=6$$ and different values for $$n_1=24,n_2=77$$ then how can the first equation be linear?

Comment: A *linear* transformation $C$ is a transformation for which the following holds: $C(\alpha x +\beta y)=\alpha C(x)+\beta C(y)$ for any $x,y$ in the space that the $C$ acts on, and any constants (real, complex, or something else depending on what you're doing) $\alpha, \beta$. In particular, $C$ does not have to be a scaling, as you seem to assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a linear system due to the fact that if

$$y_1{(n1,n2)} = C_{(n1,n2)} x_1{(n1,n2)}$$

and

$$y_2{(n1,n2)} = C_{(n1,n2)} x_2{(n1,n2)}$$

then if

$$x_3 = \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2$$

it is the case that

$$y_3 = C_{(n1,n2)}[\alpha x_1{(n1,n2)} + \beta x_2{(n1,n2)}] = C_{(n1,n2)}\alpha x_1{(n1,n2)} + C_{(n1,n2)}\beta x_2{(n1,n2)} = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$$

Comment: I am starting to get how this works. But again why when I try to visualize it it doesn't make sense? I tried putting in random values of n1,n2, and graphed it using y(n1,n2) as the Y axis and x(n1,n2) as the X axis. Do you know where I can find more exercises to practise on ?

Comment: @TrtTrt, linearity doesn't mean spatial invariance.  The system is linear since $C(x_1 + x_2) = Cx_1 + Cx_2$.  The fact that $C$ is not a constant with position does not change that.